# forgot to check in unchanged version

Tags: git

This is a common problem I run into with git.  Someone sends me a set of files.  I make some changes, then commit.  Then I remember that I forgot to commit the state of the files *before* I made the changes.  I still have a copy of the original files.  How can I retroactively check in the unchanged version, then have the next commit be my changed version?

(I have tried overwriting my changed version with the old version, committing, then reordering the commits with `rebase -i`, but I always get a conflict when I try that, because my original commit *adds* all the files, and rebase doesn't seem to like reordering an *add* to be after a *modify*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the usual caution about `git reset --hard`, which throws away **uncommitted** changes as well as the changes between the original and destination commits:

```
git branch tmp
git reset --hard HEAD^
cp ../originals/* .
git add .     # or whichever specific files
git commit -m "Add original files"
git checkout tmp -- .
git commit -c tmp
git branch -D tmp
```

You could use the reflog instead of a temporary branch if you're comfortable with that, of course.